# Google Script: Find first empty cell in row, then add value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to create a macro that finds the leftmost empty cell in a row, then adds today's date to that row (as in *setFormulaR1C1('=TODAY()')* )

I have been able to get the last empty row or column from a sheet but not, specifically, the last empty cell from the row I'm standing on.

Answer (score 1):

From `I want to create a macro that finds the leftmost empty cell in a row, then adds today's date to that row (as in setFormulaR1C1('=TODAY()') )`, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to find the most left empty cell in the active row and want to put a formula of `=TODAY()` to the cell.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  const row = range.getRow();
  const values = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
  const column = values.findIndex(c => !c);
  if (column == -1) return;
  sheet.getRange(row, column + 1).setFormula("=TODAY()");
}
```

- When this script is run, please select a cell in the sheet and run the script. By this, a formula of `=TODAY()` is put into the most left empty cell of the selected row.
- When the empty cell is not found, the script is stopped.
- If you want to fix the value of `=TODAY()` as the constant value, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      sheet.getRange(row, column + 1).setFormula("=TODAY()");
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const today = new Date();
      today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      sheet.getRange(row, column + 1).setValue(today);
    ```

#### References:

- [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactiverange)
- [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike! That's working well but missing an aspect – it seems that the script does not add values if a Cell with (today) is present on the row.

Is there any line of code that is checking for that?

EDIT: As a matter of fact, it doesn't seem to add anything if there's ANY cell with a date on it.

Comment: @Adam Nasimoff Thank you for replying. From `That's working well`, I understood that your question was resolved. About `it seems that the script does not add values if a Cell with (today) is present on the row. Is there any line of code that is checking for that? EDIT: As a matter of fact, it doesn't seem to add anything if there's ANY cell with a date on it.`, I think that this is a new question. Because my proposed script is for `I want to create a macro that finds the leftmost empty cell in a row, then adds today's date to that row (as in setFormulaR1C1('=TODAY()') )`.

Comment: @Adam Nasimoff But, I would like to support you. Now, I cannot understand the relationship between `it seems that the script does not add values if a Cell with (today) is present on the row. Is there any line of code that is checking for that? EDIT: As a matter of fact, it doesn't seem to add anything if there's ANY cell with a date on it.` and your question. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you the detail of your actual expected question? If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?